# How to remove duplicate entry from ruby hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have query result hash.

```
 hotels = [#<Hotel id: 42, hotel_name: "Vijay: Resort De Alturas,Candolim", stars: "4">, #<Hotel id: 42, hotel_name: "Vijay: Resort De Alturas,Candolim", stars: "4">, #<Hotel id: 47, hotel_name: "locard", stars: "3", >, #<Hotel id: 48, hotel_name: "testtttt", stars: "1">, #<Hotel id: 41, hotel_name: "Vijay: Krish Holiday Inn,Baga", stars: "2">, #<Hotel id: 43, hotel_name: "Indian hotel", stars: "3">, #<Hotel id: 39, hotel_name: "Vijay: Estrela Do Mar, Calangute", stars: "3">, #<Hotel id: 41, hotel_name: "Vijay: Krish Holiday Inn,Baga", stars: "2">, #<Hotel id: 39, hotel_name: "Vijay: Estrela Do Mar, Calangute", stars: "3">, #<Hotel id: 40, hotel_name: "Estrela Do Mar, Calangute", stars: "3">, #<Hotel id: 44, hotel_name: "Taj hotel", stars: "3">, #<Hotel id: 46, hotel_name: "mobile hotel", stars: "3">, #<Hotel id: 41, hotel_name: "Vijay: Krish Holiday Inn,Baga", stars: "2">, #<Hotel id: 40, hotel_name: "Estrela Do Mar, Calangute", stars: "3">, #<Hotel id: 47, hotel_name: "locard", stars: "3">, #<Hotel id: 45, hotel_name: "The malwa", stars: "3">, #<Hotel id: 40, hotel_name: "Estrela Do Mar, Calangute", stars: "3">, #<Hotel id: 42, hotel_name: "Vijay: Resort De Alturas,Candolim", stars: "4"]
```

and

```
hotels.map(&:id)
=> [42, 42, 47, 48, 41, 43, 39, 41, 39, 40, 44, 46, 41, 40, 47, 45, 40, 42]
```

and I want to delete duplicate hash value from `hotels` and remain hash like

```
hotels.map(&:id)
=>  [42, 47, 48, 41, 43, 39, 40, 44, 46, 45]
```

I tried

```
hotels.uniq { |i| i[:id] }.map(&:id)
Hotel Load (0.4ms)  SELECT DISTINCT `hotels`.* FROM `hotels` INNER JOIN `package_prices` ON `package_prices`.`hotel_id` = `hotels`.`id` WHERE `hotels`.`searchable` = 1 ORDER BY package_prices.price
=> [42, 48, 41, 39, 43, 46, 44, 45, 47, 40]
```

But this changed the order which I want `[42, 47, 48, 41, 43, 39, 40, 44, 46, 45]`

Comment: The first piece of code is showing a Array of Hotel objects, not a Hash. To get what you want: `hotels.map(&:id).uniq` -- Actually if you still have the ActiveRecord::Relation (like your console output suggest), you could directly use: `hotels.pluck(:id)`

Comment: @MrYoshiji I want uniq Array of Hotel in given sequence

Comment: @MrYoshiji hotels.pluck(:id) return  [42, 42, 47, 48, 41, 43, 39, 41, 39, 40, 44, 46, 41, 40, 47, 45, 40, 42] But i want arrays of hash in which id in the order `[42, 47, 48, 41, 43, 39, 40, 44, 46, 45]`

Comment: why would the order matter?

Comment: @MoisesZaragoza, Because this is sorted array of record by hotel price

Comment: Is the `hotels` object AREL .?

Comment: then use `hotels.uniq`

Comment: @MrYoshiji `hotel.uniq.map(&:id)` return `[42, 48, 41, 39, 43, 46, 44, 45, 47, 40]` But I dont want in this sequence

Comment: Try @MrYoshiji original suggestion of `hotel_hash.map(&:id).uniq`. Does that maintain the desired order?

Comment: @MrYoshiji, I have updated variable

Comment: `hotels.uniq` will return a Array (list) of Hotel objects. `hotels.uniq.map(&:id)` will return the id of each hotel of the hotels list.

Comment: @VijayChouhan the insistence that you want this in a particular sequence is a code smell to me. You should be fetching these either through an AREL association or through Pure SQL. Once you start using map you're at the ruby layer. I would hope that you aren't then going to fetch those IDs via a SQL get such as __'id' IN ?, hotels_hash.map(&:id)__

Comment: @MrYoshiji, You are right it return uniq hotels list but not maintain the sequence. It replacing the place of many ids like 48, 47 an so on, I want id in same sequence as hotels.map(&:id)

Comment: If it is still a ActiveRecord::Relation object (which should be true in your case), do `hotels.uniq.order(:price)` (re-order by price after doing a uniq constraint)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just call `uniq!` method to change hotels array in-place, `uniq!` takes a block where you can return what you are comparing

```
hotels.uniq!{|hotel| hotel.id}
```

e.g. see usage

```
irb(main):001:0> class Hotel
irb(main):002:1> attr_reader :id
irb(main):002:1> def initialize(id, name)
irb(main):003:2> @id = id
irb(main):004:2> @name = name
irb(main):005:2> end
irb(main):006:1> end
=> nil
irb(main):008:0> hotels = [Hotel.new(1,'one'), Hotel.new(1,'one'), Hotel.new(2,'two'), Hotel.new(2,'two')]
=> [#<Hotel:0x007fa6b9148c48 @id=1, @name="one">, #<Hotel:0x007fa6b9148b58 @id=1, @name="one">, #<Hotel:0x007fa6b9148a40 @id=2, @name="two">, #<Hotel:0x007fa6b9148950 @id=2, @name="two">]
irb(main):013:0> hotels.uniq!{|hotel| hotel.id}
=> [#<Hotel:0x007fa6b9148c48 @id=1, @name="one">, #<Hotel:0x007fa6b9148a40 @id=2, @name="two">]
```

Answer (score 0):

You actually are just slightly off the track.

`hotel_hash.map(&:id).uniq`

Comment: This will just returns a list with unique ids, I think he wants original array to be a unique list of hotels

Comment: I think that `ruby's` `uniq` does preserve the order. Tried it out in `irb`.

Answer (score -3):

I have found solution of my question's

```
@hotels = []
hotels.map{|hotel| @hotels << hotel unless @hotels.map(&:id).include? hotel.id}
```

and now `@hotels.map(&:id)` return `[42, 47, 48, 41, 43, 39, 40, 44, 46, 45]`

Comment: very inefficient, as creates list twice + loops thru n*n times

Comment: You are creating an array with all hotels, just to search for one `hotel.id`. Then you recreate the same array and search for the next id, over and over again.